# placing 3 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

**Index code**

```
     <div id="pageMiddle">
    <div id="midleft">This is a test to make sire everything is ok. This text will be removed once the test is complete and everything is working fine.</div>

<div id="midmid"><?php include_once("modules/twitter_twr.php"); ?></div>

<div id="midright"><?php include_once("modules/random_profiles.php"); ?></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #pageMiddle {
     width: 1000px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     height: 900px; 
}
#pageMiddle > #midleft {
     width: 200 px;
     margin: 0px;
     float: left;
}
#pageMiddle > #midmid {
     width: 600px;
     margin: 0px;
     display: inline;
}
#pageMiddle > #midright {
     width: 200px;
     margin: 0px;
     float: right;
}
```

I have tried many ways to do this. I just can't seem to get my head around it at all. I am trying to get it so all divs sit nicely next to each other so I able to fill them with content for the index page basically. Thanks for your time to look at it and I hope you can correct my mistakes as I suck at CSS.

Comment: Use `display:inline-block` on all elements instead of f'ing around with floats. Most certainly never use `display:inline` on a fixed size block unless you know very damn well what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment. I will sort it now

Comment: I'd like to note that doing `#id0 > #id1` is a bit overkill. `#id1` is more than enough, since id's are unique anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aYUfeyOR/4/)***
Actually this is all you need:

```
#pageMiddle {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 900px;
}
#pageMiddle > div{
  float: left;
}
```

than you can just set your widths:

```
#midleft,   #midright {
    width: 200px;
}
#midmid {
    width: 600px;
}
```

<sub>**Note** there's no need to use `#pageMiddle > #midleft` cause `ID` is already unique-per-page.</sub>

Comment: still no good http://gyazo.com/129037d719a47e8ce991d61453d60816 http://gyazo.com/053ab8799c679c6e0ba1c3083728f1d4 http://gyazo.com/e1c1e9bf3bfec108d126504cc2d9d0e4

Comment: @user3192393 edit my jsBin with your code and drop a link with the issue.

Comment: Your jsbin code fixed it. I also had a margin of 5px on my logo what was messing with the borders for my main content. You are a legend dude. Thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `display:inline` does not allow you to use the width attribute in CSS.

This should fix it with the current code you have now:

```
#pageMiddle {
     width: 1000px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     height: 900px; 
}
#midleft {
     width: 200px;
     margin: 0px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
}
#midmid {
     width: 600px;
     margin: 0px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
}
#midright {
     width: 200px;
     margin: 0px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
}
```

Also, since you're using floats, it's generally best to have your float divs lay above non-float divs (if you're trying to achieve a single row).  Your HTML syntax should be as follows:

```
<div id="pageMiddle">
    <div id="midleft">This is a test to make sire everything is ok. This text will be                 removed once the test is complete and everything is working fine.</div>

    <div id="midmid"><?php include_once("modules/twitter_twr.php"); ?></div>

    <div id="midright"><?php include_once("modules/random_profiles.php"); ?></div>
</div>
```

**Here's the fiddle (added backgrounds so you can see the distinction between divs):** http://jsfiddle.net/g732A/1/

Note that this isn't the *best* way to write columns, but it does achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/3ed66acef2cfe6af5634674e5047d5f4 http://gyazo.com/dd183dfe82a6242e72e7b4fb6315dea9 http://gyazo.com/580b9d4714415e790caaa8eedd6663f7

Comment: @user3192393 I've updated the code and fiddle.  This should work now.  Note that I've moved midmid back to its middle position.